# Many regression lines in a plot

Tags: time-series, r, plotting, rstudio

[image]

[image]

How do you plot many regression lines in a plot? This concerns the textbook question from "Forecasting: Principles and Practice". A dataset concerns winning times of Olympic running events. Categories include year, length (distance), sex (gender). The question askes to make a regression line for each plot to see the average rate of change for each event.

I could brute force this question but I want to find an efficient way to make multiple regression lines in a single plot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the dataset but normally this would be done much more easily using the `color` dimension, something like this:

```
ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=Time, color=Length))
  +geom_point()
  +geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

Note that you may have to convert `Length` to a factor first, or use `color=as.factor(Length)` in `aes`.

Comment: thanks Erwan. this was pretty helpful